# Problem in nested parent-entity relationship in ecs

Tags: java, libgdx, entity-system, entity-component

In the given flow, the `character` is the parent entity, `gun` is child of *character* and `bullet` is child of *gun*. I've got a component called `NodeComponent` which has the storage of child entities and a `NodeSystem` that iterate the children then update its position relative to its parent. The problem is when the iteration reach to the bullet, it takes some time to update the bullet position. So when I move the parent the bullet is noticeable. How do I handle the parent-child relationship transformation without losing or slowing down the update from top to bottom?

```
Character >>
             Gun >>
                    Bullet
```

Comment: Is the bullet inside the gun?

Comment: yes, it was. ..

Comment: Once the gun shoots the bullet, there is no longer a parent-child relationship. The gun should have all the information to _spawn_ the bullet, but the bullet should be a child of the main node of your environment, not be a child of the gun.

Comment: hmmm I can't understand why the bullet should be the child of main node?

Comment: I got a different animations of a gun so the gun hole position will change

Comment: Then I don't really understand the question. In real life, once you shoot a bullet with a gun, the bullet is no longer linked to the gun, in any way. It's free. It's living its own life! It's as free as the player. Once I hit the trigger, the bullet is gone and even though I move gun, there is no way I can influence the trajectory.

Comment: That's it! I just overthink, your right. Can you add answer to my question? so I could mark you as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relationship between the `Gun` and the `Bullet` is purely 'spawner/spawned'. It's not parent-child.

In real-life, when you shoot a bullet with a gun, both objects are no longer linked: you can move the gun as you want, once the bullet is out of the barrel, there's nothing you can do to change its trajectory.

So in your case, you should make the bullet as a sibling of the player, and not a child of the gun.